# Find the range of a given representing matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Given the following:

> Let $T:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ be a linear transformation. And let $B = ((1,1,1),(1,1,0),(1,0,1))$ be a basis of $\mathbb R^3$.
>
> The representing matrix of the transformation is as follows: $[T]_B = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\3&2&1\\2&1&1\end{bmatrix}$
>
> Find a basis to the range ($Im T$) and the Kernel ($ker T$)

I've found the kernel by taking a generic vector from $\mathbb R^3$, applying the coordinates of the basis on it and found that $ker T = Sp{(1,0,0)}$.

I'm just not sure how to go about finding the range.

As far as I know, the steps to find it are as follows:

1. Transpose the representing matrix.
2. Use elementary actions to bring it to a canonical form.
3. Restore the given matrix to a vectors via the basis coordinates.

I'm failing to understand the last part, here's what I've found:
$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1/2\\0&1&1/2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

How do I restore these vectors via the basis coordinates?

EDIT: Fixed the wrong basis B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates $[x,y,z]$ in the ordered basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ represent the vector $xv_1+yv_2+zv_3$ in the standard basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ (assuming $v_i$ are written in standard basis).

---

For the kernel basis, take $v\in\Bbb R^3$ in basis $B$.

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\3&2&1\\2&1&1\end{bmatrix}v=0$ gives $v=\begin{bmatrix}-k\\k\\k\end{bmatrix}$ which is the linear span of $-[1,1,1]^T+[1,1,0]^T+[1,0,1]^T=(1,0,0)$ in the standard basis.

---

Note that the range-space of a linear transformation is its column space (subspace spanned by column vectors) or the row-space of its transpose. You have found the linearly independent rows of $[T]_B^T$ as $[1,0,1/2]^T,[0,1,1/2]^T$ which serve as the basis vectors of the range in basis $B$. In the standard basis,

$$~[1,0,1/2]^T_S=1[1,1,1]^T+0[1,1,0]^T+\frac12[1,0,1]^T\\~[0,1,1/2]^T_S=0[1,1,1]^T+1[1,1,0]^T+\frac12[1,0,1]^T$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Shubham. 
But are you sure about my kernel basis being incorrect? To find it, I've taken a generic vector $v \in \mathbb R^3, v = (x,yz)$ applied the coordinates on it such as: $[(x,y,z)]_B = (-x+y+z, x-z, x-y)^t$ Multiply this vector by the transformation matrix, and you find $z =0, 2y+z = 0, y+z = 0$, which means the Kernel is $Sp{(1,0,0)}$

I want to say thanks again for the range of the transformation, Shubham.

Also, an additional aspect of the problem which I did not add, as it's related to another subsection is that $(1,0,0) \in ker T$

Comment: @EatayMizrachi Since you have fixed the question now, our answers match.